# Length of fibers of $(\mathbb{A}^n)^d\to\mathrm{Sym}^d(\mathbb{A}^n)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, invariant-theory

Let $k$ be a field, consider the canonical morphism  $f\colon (\mathbb{A}_k^n)^d\to\mathrm{Sym}^d\mathbb{A}_k^n$. 
Is there an explicit bound on the length of fibers of $f$ in terms of $n,d,\mathrm{char}(k)$?

(For example, in case $n=2,d=2$, we know $f$ is induced by inclusion $$k[x_1x_2,x_2+x_2,y_1y_2,y_1+y_2,x_1y_1+x_2y_2]\to k[x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2],$$ thus the fiber over $(O,O)$ if $k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2,2xy)$, which has length $4$ if $\mathrm{char}(k)=2$ and length $3$ otherwise. But the calculation of invariant polynomials gets harder with larger $d$.)

Comment: There is an elementary upper bound of $(d!)^n$ independent of the characteristic.  Presumably you are looking for a better upper bound than this.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks! I was thinking given a the rational point on $\mathrm{Sym}^d(X)$, what is the best thing we can we say about zero cycle on $X$?

Comment: I assume that you are asking what is the minimal degree of a zero cycle on $X$ under the hypothesis that $\text{Sym}^d(X)$ has a $k$-rational point.  Certainly there is an effective zero cycle of positive degree $\leq d$.  I am not sure that I see the connection with the question in the post.

Comment: @JasonStarr By the effective zero cycle of degree $\leq d$, do you mean taking the reduced part of the fiber over the point in  $\mathrm{Sym}^d(X)(k)$? Could it happen that the fiber is spectrum of a nonperfect field？

Comment: When $n=2$, Haiman's famous "$(n+1)^{n-1}$ theorem" says that the fiber over the graded maximal ideal has length $(d+1)^{d-1}$. (Your d and n are switched from Haiman's.) This was very hard and I don't think people have many ideas about how to generalize it beyond $n=2$.

Comment: You are correct: purely inseparable extensions are a problem.  If $X$ is smooth of dimension $n$, then for every integer $d$, for the integer $e=\text{max}\{ap^{nr}: a\geq 1, r\geq 0, ap^r \leq d\}$, for every $k$-point of $\text{Sym}^d(X)$, there is a closed point $y$ of $X$ with $[\kappa(y):k]\leq e$ such that the associated $\overline{k}$-point of $\text{Sym}^d(X)$ equals the base change of $[y]$ plus an effective zero-cycle on $X\times_{\text{Spec}\ k}\text{Spec}\ \overline{k}.$